# How to modify string value in given column and create different column with it in pandas data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to learn pandas. Currently working on a car price prediction algorithm. Registration_date data is given in year/month/day (it is a string not in date class) format like this:

```
Index Registiration_date
0     2012-02-01
1     2016-04-01
2     2012-04-01
3     2014-07-01
4     2014-12-01
5     2011-05-01
6     2009-05-01
7     2009-08-01
8     2004-07-01
```

I want to have the year data from this in a new column. What is the fastest way to do this?
The data I am working on is [this](https://www.kaggle.com/danielkyrka/bmw-pricing-challenge)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
The `datetime` tutorials teach you how to extract dates; how did your research not lead you there?  Do you need more help with search terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you assign your data as 'df'. Here is the answer.

```
df['year'] = df['Registiration_date'].str.split('-')[0][0]
```

Comment: It is not an datelike value it is a string. Sorry I forgot to mention that. dt is not working.

Comment: I updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution with for loop thanks to person above.
First create a new column.

```
df["year"] = "year"
```

Then fill the column with the data

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i,"year"] = df.loc[i,"registration_date"].split('-')[0]
```